# Microservices: API Gateway, Auth, UserManagement services

Tags: microservices

I am wondering: should UserManagement service handle user password in case of registration? I mean password doesnt store inside UserManagement Service. I think Auth service should handle UserRegistered event and that event should be declared inside API Gateway. Or what the common solution? Thx

Answer (score 0):

there might be a Identity Service which is responsible for user and service Authentication/Authorization mostly based on OAuth and OIDC. the api gateway is mainly a proxy that forwards request and response to services (ofcourse it is also responsible for other actions such as rate limiting and load balancing etc) and the identity server is one of the services behind api gateway.